# How to come out of Sub-dir & enter Home Dir in Chrooted VSFTPD?

Tags: vsftpd

I have hosted a vsftp server on RHEL7. I have multile users who login to the vsftp server. This VSFTP is chrooted. My requirement is that some of the users should landup in their home dir and the rest in specific subfolder inside their home dir. The users who land inside the subfolder should be ABLE to enter their respective home directory.

Example passwd entry for john:

**john:x:1234:123:Test account :/ftp/home/john/./test:/etc/ftponly**

With the above configuration, when  john logs into the VSFTP server he will be placed in the "test" folder in his home directory. But, when I do "cd .." he is not able to enter "/ftp/home/john/" folder.

**My Requirement**:
john should be able to enter /ftp/home/john/ folder. but NOT /ftp/home/

Here is the content of my `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
local_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `/ftp/home/john/./test` is a valid `passwd` entry, the dot `.` here assumes no sence

```
-bash-4.1$ echo $HOME
/home/testuser/./test
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/testuser/./test
-bash-4.1$ cd ..
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/testuser
-bash-4.1$ cd test
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/testuser/test
```

So home dir of user `john` is `/ftp/home/john/test` not `/ftp/home/john` like you assumes. In order to allow user `john` to reach `/ftp/home/john` you need to set its home folder to `/ftp/home/john` (or higher). In `vsftpd` (and mostly generally) chrooted users cannot get higher than their homes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The reason why I put "." dot is that, we have legacy system running wu ftp where the user logs into the test folder when he gives username and password. He can do "cd .." and enter his home directory.But, he cannot go beyond his home directory. I wanted the same setup to be replicated in vsftpd but didn't find any technique to achieve this. Hence I posted to see if there was a work around. Thanks for your reply once again!!